# A selection pattern for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, template-meta-programming

In simulating physical equations (such as fluid dynamics) it is common to write an application that deals with 1, 2, and 3 dimensions. A common C/Fortran approach is to make all vectors (for example) have a size of 3, and then to carry around a global constant to say how many elements are valid.

We have tried to use C++11 templating to serve the same purpose and the majority of our application is now templated by `int DIM`.

There are times that the difference between API for different dimensions requires entirely new classes. For this, we have come up with the following selector pattern -- it seems to be working well, but I was wondering if we have reinvented the wheel and missed something along the way?

In order to construct the pattern, we need several files:

#### `ClassName_fwd.h`:

This allows the user to reference the specific implementation of the dimension specific classes in a way that is consistent for all dimensions.

```
// forward decs
class ClassName_1;
class ClassName_2;
class ClassName_3;
template<int DIM>
struct ClassNameSelector { };
// 1D
template<>
struct ClassNameSelector<1> {
using ClassName = ClassName_1;
};
// 2D
template<>
struct ClassNameSelector<2> {
using ClassName = ClassName_2;
};
// 3D
template<>
struct ClassNameSelector<3> {
using ClassName = ClassName_3;
};
// typedef
template<int DIM>
using ClassName = typename ClassNameSelector<DIM>::ClassName;
```

#### `ClassName.h`

```
#include <path/to/ClassName_fwd.h>
#include <path/to/ClassName_1.h>
#include <path/to/ClassName_2.h>
#include <path/to/ClassName_3.h>
```

#### `ClassName.cpp`

```
// explicit instantiations
template struct ClassNameSelector<1>;
template struct ClassNameSelector<2>;
template struct ClassNameSelector<3>;
```

#### `ClassName_N.h/cpp` [optional]

Holds all of the functionality that can be implemented without care for dimension, in addition to pure virtual methods that should be overridden by the dimension-specific implementations. This class sets the dimensionless API for `ClassName`. In the `cpp` file, there should be explicit instantiations of this class. This class might be excluded to avoid pure virtual function calls.

```
/**
* All of the functions that have a constant implementation
* for all dimensions
*/
template<int DIM>
class ClassName_N {
    // non-dimensional functions, i.e.
    void somethingDimensionless(
        const std::array<double, DIM>& dblArray
    ) const;
};
```

#### `ClassName_[1,2,3].h/cpp`

Implements the [1,2,3] dimension version of the class. This should implement the pure virtual functions of `ClassName_N` in addition to any functions specific to the particular dimension. These addition functions can only be called from other dimensionally specific implementations, otherwise the compiler will complain.

```
/**
* The dimensionally specific API's
*/
class ClassName_1 : public ClassName_N<1> {
    // dimensional functions, i.e.
    void somethingIn1D() const;
};
```

#### Usage

```
#include <path/to/ClassName.h>

template<int DIM>
void useAnyDimension(const ClassName<DIM>& c) {
    std::array<double, DIM> arr;
    c.somethingDimensionless(arr);
}

void doSomethingIn1D(const ClassName<1>& c) {
    c.somethingIn1D();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ClassName<1> oneD;
    ClassName<2> twoD;

    // dimension-less 
    useAnyDimension(oneD);
    oneD.somethingDimensionless({0.1});
    twoD.somethingDimensionless({0.1, 0.5});

    // dimension specific
    doSomethingIn1D(oneD);
    oneD.somethingIn1D();

    // the following would give compile-time errors
    //doSomethingIn1D(twoD);
    //twoD.somethingIn1D();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems unnecessary complicated. Why not just have one simple class template:

```
template <int DIM>
class ClassName {
public:
    using array = std::array<double, DIM>;

    void somethingDimensionless(const array& dblArray) const;

    template <int D = DIM,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<(D == 1)>>
    void somethingIn1D() const {
        ...
    }
};
```

And use it directly:

```
ClassName<1> oneD;
ClassName<2> twoD;
```

We use SFINAE instead of a `static_assert` in case you want to write a type trait to check for the existence of `somethingIn1D`. With a `static_assert`, `ClassName<2>{}.somethingIn1D()` wouldn't compile but overload resultion would still find it.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen `std::enable_if` before. This will certainly work on some of the smaller classes, but we also have others that have significantly different APIs between dimension for which this would end up being a bit clunky.

Comment: Just to note: `std::enable_if_t` is only c++14

Comment: @BrT You can always write the alias yourself in C++11.